# Extensions installing failed in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vsix, visual-studio-2022

I was trying to install several extensions in Visual Studio 2022 17.0.5 version. But every time I am getting this error in the VSIX installer. Screenshot in link
[VSIX installer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPWmY.png)

the installation log file shows the following lines-

```
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - -------------------------------------------
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - 17.0.5234
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - -------------------------------------------
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - Command line parameters:
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:17.0.32112.339,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXf154kdcy.vsix
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - -------------------------------------------
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - -------------------------------------------
1/15/2022 12:07:57 PM - System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.SetGlobalLogger(IInteropLogger logger)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I couldn't understand the log file. Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extension are built for x86?

Comment: No, I used those extensions before. Those worked totally fine that time.

Comment: Also. On vs2022? Or have they worked fine on 2019?

Comment: "those extensions" - all extension must be updated in various ways to work with VS 2022, which is now a 64 bit app (previuosly a 32 bit app)

Comment: Yes, all extensions were working on previous version of VS22.. not working after updating to 17.0.5.

Comment: The log shows the installer is throwing a BadImageFormatException, when loading an assembly. Almost always encountered when a 64bit app tries to load a 32bit assembly, or vice versa. Sadly, it doesn't say which assembly. Are you seeing similar issues with other .VSIX installations, or just this one? Also, can you glean any useful details from the Windows Event logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution but a workaround:
I encountered the very same error when removing Visual Studio 2019 to fully rely on Visual Studio 2022.
Reinstalling a leight-weigth version of VS2019 to have access to its VSIXInstaller.exe worked for me.

[image]

Note: This seems not to happen on every machine. I tried same setup on a virtual machine and had no need for VS2019. So this might only occur on computers that had formerly an older version of Visual Studio installed.